# Found nil while unwrapping optional value JSON Serialization

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I perform a `NSURLSession` to get data from a php, which is a JSON. When I do `NSJSONSerialization` and store it as a `NSArray` everything works fine but when I try to access an element of it to put it in a table view it crashes with the error found nil while unwrapping an optional value. The JSON it returns looks like this:

```
[
   {
   "title":"data",
   "value":"data"
   }, ...
]
```

The code I'm using to get the value is:

```
self.arrayJSON[indexPath.row]["title"]
```

And when I try this in the Xcode console returns this:

```
▿ Optional(some data)
 - Some : some data
```

EDIT:

JSON parsing code:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        do {
            let responseJSON : NSArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! NSArray
            self.arrayJSON = NSMutableArray(array: responseJSON)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.listaAnuncios.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print("json error")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: You may want to show the code when you parse json.

Comment: Assuming the lldb command you're using is `po self.arrayJSON`, what do you get if you type `po self.arrayJSON!` ?

Comment: firstly debug for self.arrayJSON[indexPath.row]

Comment: @RichTolley Yes, I use po self.arrayJSON[indexPath.row]["title"], when I do `po self.arrayJSON!` I get `error: <EXPR>:1:15: error: cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'NSMutableArray'
self.arrayJSON!
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^`

Comment: Cool, what do you get if you add ! to your original command to unwrap the optional?

Comment: Also you seem to be calling `reloadData()` twice on different threads in your parsing code

Comment: @RichTolley Same as before.. `▿ Optional(some data)
 - Some : some data`

Comment: @RichTolley I already get rid of one, but thanks!

Comment: Strange, it should either crash or unwrap the data. Try assigning it to a variable and printing it in code.

Comment: Also, as a side note, it's generally bad form to force unwrap optionals in the way your are doing in `let responseJSON : NSArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,options:[])....` Use an if let instead. Your code will crash if you ever get a `nil` response

Comment: Why are u using  self.arrayJSON = NSMutableArray(array: responseJSON) ? self.arrayJSON is array or NSMutableArray?

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder self.arrayJSON is a `NSMutableArray`. I do so because I need to use the array in the table view methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! It wasn't because of accessing to the element, it was because the cell was nil. I was using this:

```
let cell : CustomCell = CustomCell()
```

and I changed it for this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```